# Как создать манифест для Jar?

Tags: java, manifest

Есть папка Test. Внутри файл manifest.mf и класс OhMyGoshClass с методом main. В manifest.mf прописано:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Bluh
Main-Class: OhMyGoshClass
Символ перехода на новую строку в конце есть, но все равно jar-файл не запускается.

Answer (score 1):

Если  Вы используете  при  разработке проекта Maven и Вы не хотите тратить время на написание манифеста, то добавьте в ваш проект следующий плагин :

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>
                                        пакет(если есть).EXEC_CLASS_NAME
                                    </mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Пример mainClass:

```
<mainClass>
com.test.Main
</mainClass>
```